# What is the best practice for displaying a user's profile photo?

Tags: upload, photo, profile, gravatar

A customer has asked me to build them an online application that allows a user to upload their profile photo. What I am trying to understand is it is best practice to implement a Gravatar or allow them to upload a new photo?

If it is better to use Gravatar will most average users know how to do that? Is there a DotNet plugin available to do that? Or it is better to allow them to upload their photo and use a face-detection plugin to display the best photo possible?

If uploading is the industry best practice then what are the best practices that I should follow to get the best image possible. I know that face detection would be good to use so that users are seeing the face in the profile photo.

Any help is appreciated on this question.

Comment: I should also add a little background.... the user has the option to sign up with their email address or facebook or linked in. I know that if a person selects Facebook or LinkedIn I can get their profile image from the respective social media platforms. But what about if they use their email address?

Comment: If they use their email address should I try to see if they have a gravatar available? If they don't then should I allow them to upload an image?